# How do I write this in SCSS

Tags: sass, less

I'm not very familiar with SCSS and downt know how the following code should look in SCSS. I wanna add per level 20px margin.

```
.level-1 {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

...

.level-9 {
    margin-left: 160px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop :

```
@for $i from 1 through 9 {
    .level-#{$i} {
        margin-left: 20px * ($i - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you vor the quick response!!!